# CAML Lookup - get different value from lookup list using query

Tags: 2013, lookup-column, caml

Say I have two lists:

**Support Pack**

```
ID : 1, SupportPackTemplateLookup:(ID#OtherValue), IsActive : True
```

**Support Pack Template:**

```
ID : 1, OtherValue: x, SuppType: 10 hr support pack
ID : 2, OtherValue: y, SuppType: 20 hr support pack
```

I need to do the following query:

> ```
> Get **SuppType** for all Support Packs
> Where IsActive == true
> ```

How do I achieve this without modifying the lookup column?

Comment: Use Joins and Projected Fields to get the IsActive column

Answer (score 0):

When working with Lookup-Column use `LookupId="TRUE"` in your caml query.

Have a look at this blog post: https://abstractspaces.wordpress.com/2008/05/05/caml-query-lookup-field-by-id-not-by-value/

These projects are really helpful, when working with caml:
https://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/
http://www.u2u.be/Software
(choose one)

Comment: Hi, sorry but AFAIK using LookupId will simply return #OtherValue. If I'm wrong please supply an example.

Comment: Also, U2U does not help with Joins. I have it open right now

Comment: I see, so your problem was to get that additional column from the other list. Since Joins are not supported by either product, maybe you have a look at: https://camljs.codeplex.com/ - this could help you come up with the right query.

Answer (score 0):

Use Joins and Projected Fields to get the additional columns.. Example below

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();

query.Joins = "<Join Type='INNER' ListAlias='Support Pack'>" +
                "<Eq>" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='SuppType' RefType='Id'/>" +
                    "<FieldRef List='Support Pack' Name='ID'/>" +
                "</Eq>" +
                "</Join>";

query.ProjectedFields =
    "<Field Name='SuppIsActive' Type='Boolean' " +
            "List='Support Pack' ShowField='IsActive'/>";

query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title'/><FieldRef Name='SuppIsActive'/><FieldRef Name='SuppType' />";

SPList suppPacks = web.Lists["Support Pack Template"];
SPListItemCollection items = suppPacks.GetItems(query);
```

Comment: Where do I specify the `SupportPackTemplateLookup` field? Thanks

Comment: Which one are you referring to ?

Comment: `SupportPack.SupportPackTemplateLookup`. Is this implicitly defined, otherwise how does the CAML query know what field to Join on?

Comment: I think I have misunderstood your entire setup, can you tell me which one is the Parent List? And what fields do you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Joins to get your data. Refer to the MSDN article [List Joins and Projections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539975(v=office.14).aspx). You can also refer [this question of SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11907535/1047998) with some examples to guide you on how Joins work.